# Selenium Only local connections allowed and NoSuchSessionException

Tags: selenium, docker, virtual-machine, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I have the following docker-container

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
MAINTAINER Hasan Kara

RUN set -xe \
 \
# Install Java, Chrome, Xvfb, and unzip
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
      openjdk-8-jre \
      chromium-browser \
      xvfb \
      curl \
      wget \
      unzip \

 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \ 
 && ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome \
 \
# Download and install chrome drive and selenium server standalone
 && wget -q "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
 && wget -q "http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" \

 && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
 && mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin \
 && mv selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar /usr/local/bin

VOLUME /downloads

ENV DISPLAY :10

CMD export DISPLAY=:10 && Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1366x768x24 -ac & google-chrome --no-sandbox -remote-debugging-port=9222 & java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar &

EXPOSE 4444 9222
```

Which I run with:

```
docker run --rm -it --shm-size=512m --name chromium -p 4444:4444 -p 9222:9222 hasankarafhnw/seleniumchromium /bin/bash
```

And inside the bash I run by hand, because for some reason the CMD doesn't work...

```
export DISPLAY=:10 && Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1366x768x24 -ac & google-chrome --no-sandbox -remote-debugging-port=9222 & java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar &
```

Now I can perfectly connect to the selenium hub at "http://192.168.99.100:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html", but if try:

- Create a Session through the hub
- Create a Session with [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/haisi/514eeec884b6c45fcd8b25a79a7af2db/raw/b80b110ec5231f94431ef2634a73544affe36fbd/selenium-tester.js) **in** the container.
- Create a Session though a RemoteWebDriver running on the host-os.

I get the following error:

> Only local connections are allowed. 
>   INFO - Attempting bi-dialect
>   session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>
> INFO - Executing: [take screenshot]) WARN - Exception thrown
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session

Chromedriver: 2.27.440175
Chromium: 55.0.2883.87
Selenium-server-standalone: 3.0.1
Docker: 1.13
Host-OS: Win 7

RemoteDriveCode:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("./extension_0_2_0_10.crx"));

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL( "http://192.168.99.100:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own docker-selenium (there will be lot more bugs you will find) maybe you can simply use: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup whitelisted-ips argument for chromedriver executable (not chrome!). You can achive it by set system property `webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps` when node starts, like in your command:

```
CMD export DISPLAY=:10 && Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1366x768x24 -ac & google-chrome --no-sandbox -remote-debugging-port=9222 & java -Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps= -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar &
```